# how to add an image instead of tabIndicator color

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to use the `Image` with arrow in bottom instead of `Tab` Indicator color. I am using in built `TabbedActivity` Template.please guide me,thanks in advance. here is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReaVv.png)

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Take a look at this answer. This should help ya. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794059/how-to-add-images-as-a-tab-indicator-in-android-tab-host

Comment: Thank u kishore for editing my code..i hope u understood my requirement what i want .please help me